# nsclient++ intermittent connection refused on same subnet

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

I have setup Nagios and nsclient++ on a number of my Windows servers. They are all in the same subnet so no routing or firewall stuff is taking place in between the endpoints, and I have verified that the firewalls on the servers are not causing trouble. The problem is that the scheduled checks sometimes fail with "connection refused" and sometimes work! It is a frustrating problem to resolve because I do not know what to look for.

One place I did look is in the nsclient++ logs, where I am seeing this recurring error:

`...\trunk\modules\CheckSystem\PDHCollector.cpp:148: Failed to query performance counters: \238...`

This sounds promising, but I couldn't find much on Google about this error as it pertains to NSClient++

Comment: For better response, try posting on the Nagios board.

Comment: @mdpc, thanks for the advice - what Nagios board are you referring to?

Comment: I might try nsclient.org first.

Comment: have you checked if the nagios server is having timeouts on pings, are other service checks not based on nsclient like snmp or others causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any response from your windows server if you run this command on your nagios server?

```
./check_nrpe -H <nsclient++ server ip>
```

You should also check if your nagios server is in the allowed host under Settings.

```
[Settings]
allowed_hosts=[ nagios server ip]
```

This config file should be found under your installation file on your windows server named **nsc.ini**

If you need further help, read up the NSClient wiki found [here](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/doc/usage/nagios/nrpe#a5.NSClientconfigurationrevisited)